# remove the "App Backend" in the view in yii2

Tags: yii2

I created a controller and view using the gii tool in yii2. But in the browser it displays "App Backend" at the upper part. How can do i remove or change it?
My view file only has the following codes.

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
?>
<h1>WELCOME!!!</h1>

<p>
  Hello world.
</p>
```

and the browser displays

**App Backend

WELCOME!!!

Hello WOrld.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at

```
 \views\layout\main.php
```

probably ** App Backend  is located in this part or similar

Comment: Why did you answer this one when you didn't know the answer? Your answer is incorrect. Nothing like that in the layout.

Comment: @LarryTX  ..    because in some version of  backend/views/layout/main.php there was this text  ..  ... today .(1 year and 8 months after)   could be that the advanced layout content is changed ..